# ajax query onclick Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a working code using javascript event "onchange" :

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="change_table(this)">
```

the jquery :

```
unction change_table(elem) {

var adressesInfo;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",        
    data: {id: elem.value},

    success: function(data){
        adressesInfo = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    },

    async: false
});
```

and the php :

```
$data = array();
[...]
print json_encode($data);
```

This is working fine.

Now I want to do exactly the same, but using an onclick event on the th elements:

```
$(function(){
    $("th").on('click', function(e){
        change_table($('#mySelect')[0].value);
    });
})
```

(This might not make much sense to do, but this is just for the sake of the example)

When I do this, i get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

I'm a bit confused on why it would work with onchange event and no onclick event, what is the difference ? i'm kinda new to jquery/ajax.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `change_table` function expects an element that it can get value from (`data: {id: elem.value}`). So in the second case you should supply `mySelect` directly:

```
$("th").on('click', function(e){
    change_table($('#mySelect')[0]);
});
```

Comment: I feel dumb now, I was looking for this for like 3 hours : < tunnel vision is the worse : D

Answer (score 0):

```
$("th").click(function(){
        change_table($('#mySelect')[0].value);
    });
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is jQuery trying to parse HTML output from your PHP, which probably means your back end is raising errors, probably due to posting it the wrong data.

Your original `change_table` function takes an element as its only argument, and in your final example you are passing it the string already evaluated. Perhaps this explains why the wrong data is going to your server.

Aside: there's no need to parse the json explicitly in jQuery. You can use `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax set up and the deserialized json will be passed to your `success` handler. If it fails your `error` handler will fire instead.